# use the checkpoint feature without test step failure

Tags: hp-uft

Currently testing a WPF application (SAP Agentry) and trying to determine the status extract the status of a work order in order to perform a test that is appropriate to the work orders status.

Work order status is indicated by an image being visible on the screen.

Does anyone know if HP-UFT has any way of comparing a CheckPoint bitmap with an object on the screen to see if they match, without triggering the test to fail if they do not match.

```
WpfWindow("Agentry").WpfImage("item").check(CheckPoint("WO-InProgress"))
```

Limitations of the application:

- I do not have access to the name of the image (all images have the same properties)
- There is no isEnabled / isClickable status available (locked and enabled objects both return true for these types of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to achieve this result:

- disable all reporting (thus preventing any failed steps),
- perform the Boolean check, then take action based on result.
- Enable the reporting again (allowing pass and failures

Code:

```
Reporter.Filter = rfDisableAll 
If WpfWindow("Agentry").WpfImage("item").check( CheckPoint("WO-InProgress") ) Then
    currentState = "play"
    'Do actions relating to a in progress work order.
End If
Reporter.Filter = rtEnableAll
```